# How to ensure only A class can create an A.B instance?

Tags: c#

I have a broker class that issues request objects and expects them to be delivered back to it with a couple properties changed to sensible values. The problem is that the consumers of said broker must *never* change a couple readonly properties of that object nor be able to create a different request instance to cheat that readonly protection or the broker will break and throw an exception. I want to find a way to make the compilation fail if any class save for the broker tries to create a request object.

I think sealing the instantiation of the request objects so it can only be done from inside the broker itself is a neat idea coupled with readonly properties so request processors can never cheat the system but i am having a hard time doing so. I tried a child class with a private constructor like this:

```
public class PermissionsRequestBroker {
    public PermissionsRequest Test() {
        return new PermissionsRequest();
    }

    private class PermissionsRequest {
        private PermissionsRequest() {

        }
    }
}
```

But it fails because the broker cannot create the request object.

I tried a similar approach but with an interface like this:

```
public class PermissionsRequestBroker {
    public IPermissionsRequest Test() {
        return new PermissionsRequest();
    }

    public interface IPermissionsRequest {

    }

    private class PermissionsRequest : IPermissionsRequest {
        public PermissionsRequest() {

        }
    }
}
```

But the request processors can implement IPermissionsRequest and cheat the system that way. Sure i could implement a runtime check so the object returned is still the broker's PermissionRequest object but that's still a runtime check and will throw an exception.

I'm all for exceptions but i feel there must be some way to enforce that contract at compile time without installing any IDE extension or NuGet package of any kind.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? What do you mean by "cheat", do you not trust the user of your library? Have you looked the the `sealed` keyword?

Comment: Why have you made the constructor private in your first case? Won't making it public while the class itself is private solve your problem?

Comment: @Aron A PermissionRequest instance has a RequestId property that must never change. IE: If the broker hands you a Request with Id: 0 the broker will expect you to reply with that same id or the broker itself will break and reply to a different request source.

Comment: @Madhusudhan I return an instance of PermissionRequest to consumer classes so it _must_ be public

Comment: It's not going to be possible to stop the consumer from modifying those critical properties.  Anyone with a basic knowledge of reflection could do it. same with instantiating the class. So the most you can hope for is to slow them down.

Comment: @SamAxe I hoped for someone with more knowledge than me to prove me right but i suspected so all along. I'll have to change my broker design a bit to work around this.

Comment: If the consumers are garantueed to be in another assembly, then you can simple make the request constructor internal.

Comment: @Maarten That's a very clean approach and the reason i accepted Steve's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `PermissionsRequestBroker` and `PermissionsRequest` in a separate assembly together, and mark `PermissionsRequest` as `internal` instead of `public`. Then if you need consumers to be able to hold onto an instance of the `PermissionsRequest` object, wrap it in another class that is `public`.

Something like the following:

```
public class PermissionsRequestBroker {
   public PermissionsRequestWrapper Test() {
      return new PermissionsRequestWrapper( new PermissionsRequest() );
   }
}

internal class PermissionsRequest {
   internal PermissionsRequest() {

   }
}

// Use 'sealed' to prevent others from inheriting from this class
public sealed class PermissionsRequestWrapper {
   private PermissionsRequest _permissionsRequest;

   internal PermissionsRequestWrapper(PermissionsRequest permissionsRequest) {
      _permissionsRequest = permissionsRequest;
   }

   /* etc... */
}
```

Comment: Wow. Never thought of such a clever solution.

Comment: If the consumers of the request (or wrapper) are in the same assembly, then they can still create an instance of a wrapper. If the consumers are garantueed in another assembly, then one can simple make the constructor of the request internal.

Comment: I *did* day put them in a separate assembly ;) You're right, you can do without the wrapper, but if the intent is to hide some of the implementation details, this is one way to do it. Plus, if `PermissionsRequest` starts to get "big", it doesn't have to get cluttered with both `internal` *and* `public` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is already answered, but I'm curious... why wouldn't this work?

**EDIT**: Had a brain freeze moment, the below code will not work, see the edit after that.

```
public class PermissionsRequestBroker {
    public PermissionsRequest Test() {
        return new PermissionsRequest();
    }

    public sealed class PermissionsRequest {
        private PermissionsRequest() {

        }
    }
}
```

Basically making the inner class public and sealed but only its constructor private?

**EDIT**

If we invert this, it would be simpler to implement, thoughts? The staticness of the broker is optional of course.

```
public class PermissionsRequest
{
    private PermissionsRequest()
    { }

    public sealed class Broker
    {
        public static PermissionsRequest CreatePermissionsRequest()
        {
            return new PermissionsRequest();
        }

        public PermissionsRequest CreatePermissionsRequest_Instance()
        {
            return new PermissionsRequest();
        }
    }
}

public class UserClass
{
    public void Blah()
    {
        var permissionsRequest = PermissionsRequest.Broker.CreatePermissionsRequest();

        var broker = new PermissionsRequest.Broker();

        var permRequest = broker.CreatePermissionsRequest_Instance();
    }
}
```

Comment: The constructor is private so not event PermissionsRequestBroker can invoke it

Comment: oh, my bad, my brain was working the oppositte way where subclasses can access private stuff of parent classes.

Comment: No problem. Everyone has those moments from time to time.

Comment: I think it's a bit convoluted and not that clean or easy to understand but it should work. I've already changed my design to something that does not require the sort of trickery i asked about so i won't be using your genius in my project. Sorry about that. Still, it's a very well thought out approach, nice work.